# Submission not visible anymore after 4 months with the journal

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors, open-access

I submitted a paper to a journal and after four months, the status changed to "decision in progress". After 2 days, I cannot see my submission  anymore. I am co-author.  What happend?

Comment: I beleive you should ask the corresponding author(one who submitted the paper) rather than asking the people on Academia

Comment: Are you sure it didn't move to the "decision" tab?